# Attach onmouseover function() to all hrefs and srcs in page to access them?

Tags: javascript, anchor, href, onmouseover, queryselector

I want to access href and src links via simply attaching onmouseover = function to them. Here is my attempted codes:

HTML

```
<p><a href="https://dannychoo.com/en/instagram/p/BYnMQSpBcmY">Lass</a></p>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org">interest</a>
<p><a src="https://mirai-instagram-images.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/dannychoo/17897602822049811/21296657_120344735358000_817812329218441216_n.jpg">stuff</img></p>
```

Javascript:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a").onmouseover = function() {
let g, i; 
g = document.querySelectorAll("a").getAttribute("href")
for (i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {
location.assign(g[i]);
      }
 }
```

Thanks for your helpful answers.

Comment: You want to access the `href` and `src` of what element types? `<a>` and `<img>`?? Multiple element types can have src attributes

Comment: @justinw yes to your first question. You have a point, but I'll see what goes later down the line.

Comment: Understood, I posted an answer below that shows how to get `href` and `src` regardless of tag type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to get these attributes regardless of tag type, you can query multiple selectors with `querySelectorAll`. You can also loop through the results with `forEach`.

You can target elements by attribute with CSS, you can read more about that [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp).

Modern browsers support looping through `querySelectorAll` results, but if you need old browser support [check out this article for alternatives](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/)

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll("[src], [href]");
links.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener("mouseover", e => {
    const href = e.target.href;
    const src = e.target.getAttribute("src");
    if (src) console.log(src);
    if (href) console.log(href);
  });
});
```

```html
<p><a href="https://dannychoo.com/en/instagram/p/BYnMQSpBcmY">Lass</a></p>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org">interest</a>
<p><img src="https://mirai-instagram-images.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/dannychoo/17897602822049811/21296657_120344735358000_817812329218441216_n.jpg">stuff</p>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8trvscd2/6/)

Comment: @Manuel Roads, notice how justinw uses `.addEventListener` instead of `.onmouseover = ...` — addEventListener is preferred, as it allows you to attach multiple event listeners, where assigning `.onmouseover = ...` blindly _replaces_ any existing event listeners.

Comment: regarding ```const href = e.target.href; const src = e.target.getAttribute("src");```

why does the ```const src``` requires ```getAttribute("src")``` for src, whereas ```const href``` only requires ```e.target.href```, without ```getAttribute()``` like ```const src```?

Comment: @Stephen P, I'll remember what you said. It's better to default choose multiple event listeners, rather than blindly replacing any existing event listeners, unless in specific scenarios.

Comment: @ManuelRoads the reason I used `getAttribute("src")` is because in your **original** example, you had an `<a>` tag with a `src` element on it. That is *not* valid HTML as `src` should not be on `<a>` tags. If you were to do `e.target.src` it would come back as `undefined`. I used a proper `img` tag in my example, so using `e.target.src` would be valid, but I kept it as `getAttribute` - [check out this example](https://jsfiddle.net/y7xr3qp4/6/) - look at the console, one is `undefined` the other is showing the `value` of `foo`

Comment: Thanks, @StephenP. I appreciate your clarification. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code snippet. `document.querySelectorAll` returns an array, so you need to loop through it to attach the events.

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("a")

elements.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
        console.log(element.href);
        console.log(element.getAttribute('src'));
         } )
});
```

```html
 <p><a href="https://dannychoo.com/en/instagram/p/BYnMQSpBcmY">Lass</a></p>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org">interest</a>
<p><a src="https://mirai-instagram-images.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/dannychoo/17897602822049811/21296657_120344735358000_817812329218441216_n.jpg">stuff</img></p>
```

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("a")

elements.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    console.log(element.href);
    console.log(element.getAttribute('src'));
  })
});
```